# WP7 Show Control on top of other control

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to show control on top of other control?

If so, how?

Especially I'm interesting in showing Border control on top of WebBrowser.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can show one control on top of another. Look at the [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) attached property which is respected by all `Panel` implementations. Simply place your controls within a `Panel` so that they overlap then set their z-index accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use canvas control. Place all of the contents inside a canvas and set elements individually by Canvas.Zindex property